# Login doesn't work on 3G/4G Network with Nginx

Tags: authentication, nginx, http-headers, reverse-proxy, 3g

I've developed a web application, This app is running on Apache and Nginx (proxy_pass).
No problem with my ADSL, problems appears when I was on mobile network (3G/4G)

My application work well but when I tried to login, it fails.

If I configures server to run SSL (HTTPS), the login process works well, then I decide to check my server configuration, this was the same between HTTP and HTTPS.

Also, I check HTTP Header and I see a new HTTP header:

```
Via:1.0 proxy (proxy)
X-Cache:MISS from proxy
```

Anyone know what it is ? and why headers was added and if headers are the problem ?

**Nginx configuration:**

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name  *.example.com;
        access_log   off;
        error_log off;

        root $app_folder/www/;
        location ~ /\. { deny all; }

        location ~ ~$ { deny all; }

        location ~ \.php$ { deny all; }

        location ~ /(cart) {
                rewrite        ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
        }


        location / {
                set $var A;
                if ($remote_addr != XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) {
                        set $var "${var}B";
                }
                if ($var = AB) {
                        #return 503;
                }

                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

        include  /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;


        location ~* .(js|css|png|jpeg)$ {
                include  /etc/nginx/includes/cdn-header-cache;
        }

        location ~ /svn {
                gzip  on;
                gzip_http_version 1.0;
                gzip_comp_level 2;
                gzip_min_length 1100;
                gzip_buffers     64 8k;
                gzip_proxied any;
                gzip_types text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss  text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/json;
                gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
                gzip_disable        msie6;
                gzip_vary           on;
        }

        location /nginx_status {
                stub_status on;
                access_log   off;
                allow XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
                deny all;
        }

        error_page   500 502 504  /50x.html;

        error_page 503 /work.html;
        location = /work.html {
                root /home/website;
        }
}
```

**proxy.conf File**

```
proxy_redirect     off;
proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

client_max_body_size 1024M;
client_body_buffer_size 1024M;

proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

**cdn-header-cache file**

```
expires 3M; 
log_not_found off; 
access_log off;
add_header Cache-Control public;

# don't send cookies
fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;

# CORS config
set $cors "true";

# Determine the HTTP request method used
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    set $cors "${cors}options";  
}
if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    set $cors "${cors}get";  
}
if ($request_method = 'POST') {
    set $cors "${cors}post";
}
if ($cors = "true") {
    # Catch all incase there's a request method we're not dealing with properly
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
}

if ($cors = "trueget") {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
}

if ($cors = "trueoptions") {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    # Om nom nom cookies
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
}

if ($cors = "truepost") {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
}
```

**Apache Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/home/website/www"
    ServerAdmin postmaster@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    setenvIf Request_URI ".(jpg|jpeg|png|css|gif|ico|js)$" dontlog
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-access.log combined env=!dontlog
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-error.log

    <Directory /home/website/www/>
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apache and Nginx configuration that you're using may help.

Comment: I see you're using CORS. I'm not sure that 3G/4G will permit to use this protocol. Never checked.

Comment: CORS is used only on static file :
location ~* .(js|css|png|jpeg)$ {
    include  /etc/nginx/includes/cdn-header-cache;
}